# momentjs concat date and time not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to use momentjs to combine a date string and a time string into a single datetime moment.

**Input:**

```
console.log(values.startDate);
console.log(values.startTime);
console.log(moment(values.startDate + values.startTime, 'LLL').format('LLL'));
```

**Expected output:**

```
August 10, 2020
5:19 PM
August 10, 2020 5:19 PM
```

**Current output:**

```
August 10, 2020
5:19 PM // startTime prints correctly here
August 10, 2020 12:00 AM // but not here
```

What is going wrong with `startTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing space between the date and time

```
console.log(moment(values.startDate + values.startTime, 'LLL').format('LLL'))
```

to

```
console.log(moment(values.startDate +" "+ values.startTime, 'LLL').format('LLL'))
```

hope it fixes your issue